# Can we create marker interface in java and how to tell jvm about this interface?

Tags: java

Can we create marker or tagged interface in java? If yes means how to tell jvm to do some special kind of operation while we implements these custom interface?

Comment: of course we can, but marker interfaces are more and more replaced by annotations, so use the ones that exist, and create annotations from now on.

Comment: I would use annotations for this too, because Annotations provides possibilities like properties for some cases. And you can use it more granular, e.g. annotate only methods.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it's simply an interface with no method declarations
2. No, you cannot, but you can generalize the behavior for any object where `object instanceof MyMarkerInterface`

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course we can make marker interfaces. There are also a few of the in the JDK, such as `Serializable`.

To create one of them, do this:

```
interface TheNameOfIt {

}
```

You can mark your class with it

```
class A implements TheNameOfIt {

}
```

You can check if an object is marked by this interface by

```
if (someObj instance of TheNameOfIt) {

}
```

In fact, the JVM doesn't know that that is a "marker" interface. It looks at a marker interface the same way it looks at a normal interface. We humans see that as a marker interface because it doesn't have any methods. So we don't actually "implement" it. It just kinda serve as a marker.